# Validate relative path by the wildcard in Python

Tags: python, regex, path

I have a condition where I need to compare the relative name/path of the file (`string`) with another path that has wildcards:

```
files list:
    aaa/file1.txt
    bbb/ccc/file2.txt

accepted files by the wildcard:
    aaa/*
    bbb/**/*
```

I need to pick only those files that match to any of the wildcard masks.

```
aaa/file1.txt equals aaa/* => True
ddd/file3.txt equals aaa/* or bbb/**/* => False
```

Is that possible to do with `glob` or any other module?

**edit**: I removed all unnecessary details from the question *after* the discussion.

Comment: What do you mean by "pick only those new files that feat with any of the wilcard masks". How do you expect to "pick" these files? Where are you picking them from? What is it you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice base zip archive is big and it is present together with the other files that are unzipped. Then I receive another small update.zip that has new files together with the list of those wildcards. Second archive will be extracted. All of the new files must replace old. That's the place where I need to understand which of them are for that big zip archive.

Comment: @IgorZ I suggest simplifying and rewriting your question to get at the actual point of what you're trying to figure out, and leaving out any extra details.

Comment: @dkamins in fact a question stays the same. There is a relative name/path of the file and I need to compare it with the same relative paths that have wildcards inside.

Comment: @IgorZ I suggest you edit your question to include those details. Your comment makes clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering on my own question:

This [wcmatch](https://facelessuser.github.io/wcmatch/pathlib/) module is able to do what is required for me

```
from wcmatch import pathlib

print(pathlib.PurePath('a/a/file1.txt').globmatch('a/**/*', flags=pathlib.GLOBSTAR))
print(pathlib.PurePath('b/file2.txt').globmatch('b/**/*', flags=pathlib.GLOBSTAR))
print(pathlib.PurePath('c/file3.txt').globmatch('c/*', flags=pathlib.GLOBSTAR))
print(pathlib.PurePath('d/d/file4.txt').globmatch('d/*', flags=pathlib.GLOBSTAR))

True
True
True
False
```